# Going live with Facebook for an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have recently added Facebook integration into my iPhone app.

I am ready to submit my update to Apple, but I am not entirely sure if there is anything left to do on the Facebook side.

All my app does is post updates to your wall. This seems to work for me.

Also, does this mean my app now has encryption?

Comment: There is this in the Facebook FAQ: http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=17534. But they are not very explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Your FB app must be published and not in sandbox mode.  Verify that a FB account that is not a developer on your FB app can log in (if you're in sandbox, this will fail).